# How to get URL of each Post in php or dynamic website?

Tags: php

I am going to build a wallpapers website in php. I want to get URL of each Post. if any body have answer of my question, so please post your value able answer. I waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, i.e.

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

(Note that the double quoted string syntax is [perfectly correct](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.simple))

> Editor's note: using this code has security implications. The client
>   can set HTTP_HOST and REQUEST_URI to any arbitrary value it wants.

Comment: How I can use it for each files in the current page,

Comment: How I can use it for each files in the current page, for example, I have  a dynamic website & multiple Post at a page , how I can get URL for each post. Any Answer?

Comment: then you will have added query parameters in url .You can get them by $_GET['URL-Query'] .